# Error when updating

Tags: impresspages

I got this error message when updating to IP 4.2.6:

```
Warning: require_once(Ip/script/run.php) [function.require-once]:
failed to open stream:
    No such file or directory in /home/stenly/public_html/index.php on line 14

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]:
Failed opening required 'Ip/script/run.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php')
    in /home/stenly/public_html/index.php on line 14
```

What could have gone wrong and is there a solution to this as the website is an active and busy website?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how that could happen. But try to take Ip/script/run.php from downloaded archive (http://download.impresspages.org/ImpressPages_4_2_6.zip) and palce it on your server.

Comment: It didn't work :(
It happened, I think, because the internet connection was too slow and that it didn't download all the updates correctly ...

Comment: That shouldn't be a big problem. If there are some files missing, you can get them from downloaded archive. Are you saying, you have placed Ip/script/run.php file and still getting the same error? It is impossible as you can see from the error. Unless PHP has no right to read that file.